# Replacing Vowels In A String With Increasing Numbers

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to figure out a way to take a string and replace all the vowels with increasing number.

For example:

```
"abcdef" --> "0bcd1f"
```

I tried replaceing all vowels with a single symbol, then try replacing each occurrence of the symbol with an increasing number. This doesn't work though, because I'm setting the `word2` to something for just an instance.

```
public static String getNumberString( String s) {
    String word = s;
    String word1 = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "@");
    int c = 0;

    for( c = 0; c <= word.length(); c++) {
        String word2 = word1.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c));
    }

    return "";
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing `return "";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work. As of now you are always returning empty string.

Apart from that, in java `String` is immutable so you will need to update `word2` to have different `String` value in every iteration.

```
 public static String getNumberString( String s)
 {
     String word = s;
     String word1 = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "@");
     int c = 0;

     String word2 =  word1;
     for( c = 0; c <= word.length(); c++)
     {
           word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c));
     }

     return word2;
 }
```

Comment: That was due to typo, just rectified it.

Answer (score 1):

Well this works, and is fairly tidy code:

```
public static String getNumberString(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; s.matches(".*[AEIOUaeiou].*"); i++)
        s = s.replaceFirst("[AEIOUaeiou]", Integer.toString(i));
    return s;
}
```

Reasons why it took a lot less code:

- variables exist only if needed
- variables scope is minimised
- unnecessary steps have been removed (especially first replacing all vowels with `'@'`)
- for loop neatly expresses incrementing the vowel number and testing loop termination